# In the Element API plugin, how can I get only tags that are related to a particular section?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-elementapi

I tried to get all tags that are related to an section.
Everything I tried failed. Is there a way to get all assigned tags for a particular element type by using element criteria model.
In this case `travelImages`? I want to avoid to display not related tags.

```
'elementType' => 'Tag',
'criteria' => ['relatedto' => 'travelImages']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `relatedTo` parameter accepts either a single element ID or model, or an array of element IDs or models. It doesn't accept asset source handles, section handles, or a particular element type constant.

This means that in order to pull all tags related to a specific element type, you'll need to give the `relatedTo` parameter *an array of all IDs for that particular element type*.

You're not specific about what `travelImages` are, but assuming it's an Asset source, something like this should work:

```
'elementType' => ElementType::Tag,
'criteria' => [
    'relatedTo' => craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset, [
        'limit' => null,
    ])->ids(),
    'limit' => null,
],
```

Note that if `travelImages` isn't an Asset source, you'll need to change `ElementType::Asset` to [the appropriate element type](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/enums/ElementType.php#L21) (e.g. `ElementType::Entry`, `ElementType::Category` etc).

Comment: Doesn't work. Got an exception:  


`CException

Craft\WebApp and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "entries".`

Comment: @SiggiFoster Sorry about that – I was thinking in Twig syntax :) See updated answer above.

Comment: Works perfect. You were right. I forgot to mention what type of element travelImages are. It's an entry element type. Changed it to `ElementType::Entry` and problem solved.  Thank you very much.